# Can we configure what type of failed events should be dead lettered in Azure EventGrid?

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I have set up a HttpTriggered Azure Function that handles events from EventGrid. We have downstream APIs that we need to call, sometimes these are down or something unexpected happens. I want to store the events that fail. I have setup dead lettering. However, reading the docs, it looks like EventGrid will immediately dead letter events with these responses:

400 Bad Request, 413 Request Entity Too Large, 403 Forbidden, 404 Not Found, 401 Unauthorized

Is there a way to configure event grid to skip dead lettering of these, and only store all other codes? I don't want to clutter my storage account with these types of events, as I suspect I will see lots of 400 and 403 from some of our event sources.

I guess I can make another function that is blob that is blob triggered and deletes the events with the status codes I don't want, if that is possible. Just wondering if this is something that is possible in the setup of the dead lettering configuration in the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option here might be to add some structured exception handling within your function to manage those downstream APIs. If you don't want to dead-letter the event delivery, then catch the exception and return a different status code so that another delivery attempt will occur.

A second option could be to choose a different handler, such as a service bus queue. This will give you more control over the dead-letter process as well as accommodate for those long-running processes that may exceed the 30 second response/acknowledgement window that Event Grid expects.

Comment: I will look into Service Bus or Queue Storage, thanks!